# How can I combine multiple pngs as well as animated gifs in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have 5 transparent images and 1 animated gif

All of them have the same dimensions of 1500 x 1500 px

I need to combine them in a way that they are overlayed on top of each other

FOR EG.

body.png clothing.png jewellery.gif(24 frames)

I have tried this but the first frame is missing the clothing and the jewellery only comes from the 3rd frame

`convert body.png clothing.png null: jewellery -coalesce -composite  -layers optimize result.gif`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to overlay all of the 5 transparent images onto every frame of the animated GIF, then try:

Unix syntax:

```
convert \( image1 image2 ... image5 -background none -flatten \) null: \( animation.gif -coalesce \) -layers composite -layers optimize new_animation.gif
```

Windows syntax:

```
convert ( image1 image2 ... image5 -background none -flatten ) null: ( animation.gif -coalesce ) -layers composite -layers optimize new_animation.gif
```

Use your actual file names.

If on ImageMagick 7, use magick in place of convert.